BCC lib PT_REGS_PARM1 return value is not "this" pointer when uprobing C++ class function
What I want to probe is MongoDB server 'ServiceEntryPointMongod::handleRequest' function. 'this' pointer should be the first argument of the function. However, I used bcc 'PT_REGS_PARM1' macro to get the first argument of the function and found that it was not 'this' pointer. Finally, I got the 'this' pointer by the 'PT_REGS_PARM1' macro successfully as showed below.
enter image description here
enter image description here
Here is the target probed function of MongoDB:
DbResponse ServiceEntryPointMongod::handleRequest(OperationContext* opCtx, const Message& m);

Here is my eBPF code:
int handle_request_entry(struct pt_regs *ctx) {
    void* arg1 = (void*)PT_REGS_PARM1(ctx);
    void* arg2 = (void*)PT_REGS_PARM2(ctx);
    void* op_ctx = (void*)PT_REGS_PARM3(ctx);
    void* message = (void*)PT_REGS_PARM4(ctx);
    bpf_trace_printk("arg1: %lx, arg2: %lx\n", arg1, arg2);
    bpf_trace_printk("opctx: %lx, message: %lx\n", op_ctx, message);
}


Environment:

BCC: v0.30.0
OS: debian 10(Linux kernel 4.19.0-8-amd64)
MongoDB: 4.4.29

What is the first argument I got and why 'this' pointer is the second argument.

Please share what we need to reproduce the issue (see [mre]). I'd also advise against sharing images of the errors and code and preferring text instead.
